# How to add new excel sheet in existing excel file in runtime using java (jxl) in Webdriver

Tags: java, jxl

I have searched but i didn't get any success for finding the answer to my issue. My issue is "How to add new excel sheet in existing excel file in runtime using java(jxl) in Webdriver."

I have tried using below code, used in 2 different classes.

1st sheet:

```
FileOutputStream  fo = new 
               FileOutputStream("./700Credit_AccProfile_FV_Results_"+cdate+".xls");
WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("700Credit_FV_Zip_Results", 0);
```

2nd sheet:

```
FileOutputStream fo = new 
               FileOutputStream("./700Credit_AccProfile_FV_Results_"+cdate+".xls");
WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("700Credit_FV_City_Results", 1);
```

1st sheet is created successfully but while creating 2nd sheet, it is overwriting after execution is complete. I am using JXL . 
Please help me out with this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does this relate to WebDriver? Are we even talking about [the same WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/)? Anyway, as you said, you are rewriting the same file with new data. You should either add a new Sheet to the `wwb` instance you create in the first snippet, or if you don't have it, then open the file using `FileInputStream`, [get the workbook](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook%28java.io.InputStream%29) and add a sheet to it, then write it all out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not rewriting the same file with new data. I want to add new sheet in the existing file and write data to that sheet. But here, the existing sheet is replaced with new sheet created. I want both sheets to be present in the file. sheet1: 700Credit_FV_Zip_Results and                            sheet2: 700Credit_FV_City_Results

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code as, created both the sheets at a time and initialized the respective sheet, where required. it worked for me.

Thanks to all who viewed or replied to this question.